# Solaris11: multicast over loopback interface doesn't work

Tags: solaris, multicast

We have some processes that send data to other processes using multicast.  Up to now, we have specified a normal network interface to send / receive on, since the receiver applications are often (but not always) on different hosts from the senders.  So far, this has always worked fine, without a hitch.

We are now trying to send some of the traffic (the messages intended for receivers on the same box as the sender) via the loopback interface (by specifying "loopback" or 127.0.0.1 as the interface.)  This works fine on our development system (Solaris 10), but not on the production systems (solaris 11.)

On the Solaris 10 system, "netstat -ng" shows the group being joined on lo0.  On the solaris 11 system, it doesn't.  If I switch the receiver to listen on another interface, it works fine on both systems (the joins show up regardless of whether anybody's multicasting on the group+interface.)

I don't know if this is a Solaris 10 vs. Solaris 11 difference, or something to do with how the sysadmins for the prod systems have set things up.

Any idea what is going wrong?

If it makes any difference: we're using IPv4, the programs are written in C++.  I don't *think* the solaris 11 systems are zoned.  (I can't see why they would be, we're the only users of the machines, but you never know.)

Comment: ls /dev will show nothing if you are in a non-global zone.  And the structure of the network connection may be different between 10 and 11, especially if there are zones involved.  Do not use "loopback" just the IP 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Short answer (from Oracle, via our sysadmins):

Support for multicast over loopback was dropped in Solaris 11.  I.e., it's a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Even if true - I'm not 100% convinced - in Solaris 11 it doesn't really matter because you can just configure your own virtual network and perform MC over that.